# DynamoDb write capacity usage

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm testing DynamoDB and I made an Update Item request contaning a string with 650 chars. When I went to my AWS account, I checked the "Table capacity metrics" and I had a spike of consumed 20 WCUs (Write Capacity Units) for that operation.

[image]

In the print you can see 4 times I did the same operation and all had a spike of 20 WCUs comsumed.

```
[ObservableProperty]
private ObservableCollection<Project> projects;

private async Task SavingCloudFilesToDB()
{
     var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
     {
        WriteIndented = true,
     };
    var jsonstring = JsonSerializer.Serialize(Projects, typeof(ObservableCollection<Project>), options);
    var client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentials);
    var request = new UpdateItemRequest
    {
        TableName = "mytable",

        Key = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>
        {
            ["email"] = new AttributeValue { S = user.Email },
        },

        ExpressionAttributeNames = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            {"#string","string"}
        },

        ExpressionAttributeValues = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>()
        {
            {":string", new AttributeValue { S = jsonstring } }
        },

        UpdateExpression = "SET #string = :string",
    };
    await client.UpdateItemAsync(request);
}
```

The string passsed is a json serialization of an object:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "File",
    "CloudFiles": []
  },
  {
    "Name": "File",
    "CloudFiles": []
  },
  {
    "Name": "File",
    "CloudFiles": []
  },
  {
    "Name": "File",
    "CloudFiles": []
  },
  {
    "Name": "File",
    "CloudFiles": []
  },
  {
    "Name": "File",
    "CloudFiles": []
  },
  {
    "Name": "File",
    "CloudFiles": []
  },
  {
    "Name": "File",
    "CloudFiles": []
  },
  {
    "Name": "File",
    "CloudFiles": []
  },
  {
    "Name": "File",
    "CloudFiles": []
  },
  {
    "Name": "File",
    "CloudFiles": []
  }
]
```

I'm reading that on average, for 1Kb, 1 WCU is consumed.

"A write capacity unit represents one write per second, for an item up to 1 KB in size."

Why would DynamoDb consume 20 WCUs, for a string that shouldn't have more than 1kb in size?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you share the code and the actual item your saving, the item in your question is not a complete DynamoDB item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are making an UpdateItem request, you do not pay for the updated component, but rather the size of the entire item being updated.

My assumption here is that you have a large item and you are updating a small component of it, which is leading you to believe the consumed WCU should only be applicable to the new string being added.

If that's the case, I suggest reading this [blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/use-vertical-partitioning-to-scale-data-efficiently-in-amazon-dynamodb/).